# How to send multipart/mixed data using powershell's Invoke-Rest method

Tags: rest, powershell

I want to convert the following curl command into the equivalent Powershell command using Invoke-Rest method.

```
curl -k -i -H "Content-Type: multipart/mixed" -X POST --form 'session.id=e7a29776-5783-49d7-afa0-b0e688096b5e' --form 'ajax=upload' --form 'file=@myproject.zip;type=application/zip' --form 'project=MyProject;type/plain' https://localhost:8443/manager
```

I tried this based on the suggestions here on Stack Overflow

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -ContentType 'multipart/mixed' -InFile 'C:\Temp\myprojects.zip' -Uri https://localhost:8443/manager
```

But getting the following error

> Invoke-RestMethod : 
>   Error 500 the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
>   HTTP ERROR 500
>   Problem accessing /manager. Reason:
>       the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was foundCaused by:org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
>       at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:931)
>       at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:331)
>       at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:349)
>       at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:126)
>       at azkaban.webapp.servlet.MultipartParser.parseMultipart(MultipartParser.java:47)
>       at azkaban.webapp.servlet.LoginAbstractAzkabanServlet.doPost(LoginAbstractAzkabanServlet.java:216)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:401)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:945)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228)
>       at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
>   Powered by Jetty://

How should I send the zip file across correctly using powershell?

Comment: I suggest you grab Fiddler and look to see what is different in the Http requests between curl and PowerShell.  That is usually how I debug issues with Invoke-WebRequest/RestMethod

Comment: You may also want to check the server logs.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem, it looks like PowerShell does not work with multipart data at the moment. I found the following that illustrates a work around using .NET 4.5 methods imported in PowerShell

http://blog.majcica.com/2016/01/13/powershell-tips-and-tricks-multipartform-data-requests/